# ImageView the image is blurry

Tags: android, android-studio

I try to display an image on my app with an ImageView, but i try differents images, change the layout width and height of the cardview and imageview but nothing solve my problem.

I'm stuck on this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlDzTh4WXek&list=PLgkamPQ8kR10Fuo5sniEStusm18floyve&index=1&t=

[image: Picture screen]

[image: the original picture]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
app:cardElevation="5dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/trending1" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Hey, wolf can you make a try by adding following lines.. android:scaleType="fitXY"android:adjustViewBounds="true" and try using background instead of src

Comment: Can you add the original image? (trending1)

Comment: @HubbyTiwari i try your tips but nothing change :/

Comment: @YoavGibri image added

Comment: Try using Shapeable ImageView instead of a separate Card.

Comment: @SujalKumar why in the tutorial, he used Card and got nothing wrong and I got a problem ?

Comment: Might be due to some bug in the version of library you are using but I am not sure

Comment: Try to eliminate things.. try different image, run on different device, is it the same if the ImageView is in a Linearlayout?
Also, android:orientation="vertical" is not a part of CardView

Comment: @YoavGibri Yeah i gonna try with another Android Studio version i use at work where the imageView work. Maybe the last version of Android Studio is bugged.

Comment: Now my ImageView is working with an image url instead of one in my drawable folder lol